# Create Datetime object with specific date format

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, datetime-format

How can I create instance of `DateTime` with specific date format ?

I would like to get `DateTime` with date format like: `"yyyy-MM-dd"`.

Is is possible to get this instance like

```
var myDate = DateTime.Now.ToDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

I must have `DateTime` object not a `string`.

Comment: `DataTime` does not have a format. Only a string representation of the date has a format. Best guess is you want to parse a string in that format to a valid `DateTime`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime` is a class to store date and time information, it can be represented as `string` in very many ways (use `.ToString(format)` to specify the format required); if you want to change its *default string reprsentation* (i.e. *default format*, in order not to put `ToString(format)` everywhere within your code):

```
  CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name, true);

  culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
  culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss";

  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;

  ...

  // 2016-05-25 14:26:46 
  // since "yyyy-MM-dd" + "HH:mm:ss" is a default format now
  Console.Write(DateTime.Now);
```

so whenever `DateTime` should be represented as `string` (usually input/output operations) the format will be `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`

Comment: It's a bit risky, It needed to be handled with care and depending on requirement ... after this code has been executed every subsequent format will be changed, specially when it is done on main thread. Isn't it?

Comment: @Kylo Ren: yes, you're right, it's risky, let me quote myself: "..*whenever* `DateTime` should be represented as `string`.." with *whenever* means the entire project, subsequent formats etc.; so when establishing *default* formats one should be very meticulous and specify a lot of patterns (`LongDatePattern`, `ShortTimePattern` etc.), that's why  `ToString()` is often a better way out (esp. when one wants special format just occasionally)

Comment: hopefully the OP will take care. :) +1 cause the simplicity of answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 string fromFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
  string toFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
  string mydate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
  DateTime newDate = DateTime.ParseExact(mydate, fromFormat, null);    
  String dat = newDate.ToString(toFormat);
```

Comment: To quote OP _I must have DateTime variable not a string._

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment yet, so i have to do it this way.
See DateTime as an object with the properties "Month", "Day" and "Week". Until you print it, there is no date format. 
Are you having issues between the javascript and C# date format (and/or model binding)?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what the question is. I think Stephen provided an answer. DateTime does not have a format. But if not then I guess it's one of the following:

**1) How to parse string into a DateTime?**

```
// s is string containing date
DateTime s2d=DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**2) How to get date only component, with time 00:00:00.00000**

```
DateTime dateOnly=myDate.Date;
DateTime dateOnlyNow=DateTime.Today; // For today's date.
```

Answer (score 0):

DateTime objects can be created in different ways, e.g.:

```
    DateTime myDate0 = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime myDate1 = new DateTime(2016, 5, 25);
    DateTime myDate2 = new DateTime(2016, 5, 25, 16, 45, 59, 985);
    DateTime myDate3 = DateTime.ParseExact("2016-05-25", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Date information is variable and can be changed in different ways, e.g.:

```
    myDate0 = myDate0.Subtract(new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0));

    myDate1 = myDate1.AddYears(15);

    myDate2 = myDate2.Add(new TimeSpan(31, 7, 45, 59));

    myDate3 = myDate3.AddDays(31);
    myDate3 = myDate3.AddHours(7);
```

DateTime object can be represented as string in different ways, as written here by Dmitry Bychenko and Beldi Anouar too e.g.:

```
    string string0 = myDate0.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
     string string1 =  myDate1.ToShortDateString();
```